# How to filter a file based on specific column's value

Tags: text-processing, awk

Here is the origin data

```
TableName|Record ID|Session ID|Duration 
table1|1|1|0
table2|2|2|1
table3|3|3|1
table4|4|4|0
```

I want to show output in my linux that where the duration is not 0 value like this

```
TableName|Record ID|Session ID|Duration
table2|2|2|1
table3|3|3|1
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Literally 15 minutes reading an awk man page or googling almost any awk example would tell you how to do that. Please do that, try to solve the problem yourself, and then let us know if you have a question about your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool best suited to make decisions based on columns of line-oriented files is `awk`. Something like `awk -F "|" '$4!=0' table`, where *table* is the file containing your data. This program assumes vertical bars as column delimiters. `awk` works line by line. Its default action is to print a line when the condition given in the program is true. Here, each line where column 4 is not 0 will be printed.

For more awesome awk stuff, see the reasonably well-written [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: or just `awk -F'|' '$4' table`

Comment: Much more elegant :) But perhaps harder to understand.